# Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute from a jar file

Tags: java, jar, manifest, instrumentation

I created a jar from a single .class and I mentioned in the manifest the Premain-class, the jar was generated as expected but when I try to run a program that uses the class from that jar , I get an error

MANIFEST.MD

```
Premain-Class : Agent
```

Agent.java

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
public class Agent{
    private static Instrumentation inst;
    public static void premain(String paramString, Instrumentation paramInstrumentation) 
    { 
        inst = paramInstrumentation;
    }

    public static long size(Object paramObject)
    {
        return inst.getObjectSize(paramObject);
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
public class Test {

  public static void main (String[] args){
    System.out.println(Agent.size(Integer.valueOf(9)));
  }
}
```

When I get the Agent.class, in the same folder where MANIFEST.MD file exist I execute the following command

```
jar -cvfm agent.jar MANIFEST.MF *.class
```

and when I get the the jar I run the Test, after compiling it, as follow

```
java -javaagent:agent.jar Test
```

and I get the following error

```
Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in agent.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

am I missing something ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MANIFEST` specification doesn't seem to allow spaces after the **key**, but only before the **value**.

```
header: alphanum *headerchar ":" SPACE *otherchar newline
          *continuation
```

So this

```
Premain-Class : Agent
```

should become

```
Premain-Class: Agent
```

Also, put your `Agent` under a package, don't use the default one

```
Premain-Class: your.package.Agent
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, it was very helpful especially the `MANIFEST` specification, so the problem was resolved by eliminating the space before `:`  and also by `adding a newline`, for the package advice it has nothing to do with my problem. thanks

Comment: @octopus awesome! Remember to mark the answer as accepted, so others know it is a working solution. The package was more of an advice.

Comment: @octopus  It was the missing newline that was killing me -- Thank you!!!