# Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute for java agent

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, javaagents

I am trying to run a java agent. My docker file to create container:

```
FROM ${my_repository}/open-jdk:1.8.0.262.b10-el_8-2020.09.15-1

ENV AGENT_HOME=/usr/local/agent
ENV AGENT_CONF="$AGENT_HOME/conf"

COPY jmx_javaagent.jar $AGENT_HOME

WORKDIR $DOMAIN_ROOT

ENTRYPOINT ["./start.sh"]
CMD []
```

And start script addsjmx parameters to jvm parameters. As a summary in the script:

```
...
java -javaagent:${AGENT_HOME}/jmx_javaagent.jar=${AGENT_PORT}:${AGENT_CONF}/config.yaml \
         -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=${JMX_REMOTE_PORT} \
```

When I run the image on kubernetes, I am getting :

```
Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in /usr/local/agent/jmx_javaagent.jar
```

So what is wrong here ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute from a jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259056/failed-to-find-premain-class-manifest-attribute-from-a-jar-file)

Comment: I am using prometheus agent, so I have only jar file. I do not have Manifest.MD

Comment: Did it works without docker and kubernetes? (aka local)

Comment: what I found is, when I decompile jar, in the manifest.mf there is not an attribute "Premain-Class". Instead there is Main-Class attribute. So that should be the problem. but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: `java -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.14.0.jar=8080:config.yaml -jar yourJar.jar` this don't work?

Comment: ok I found out the solution. I just changed the version which I used to newer version (which has that attribute in manifest file) and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by using different version. In the version which I was using, I decomposed jar file and saw that there was not Premain-Class attribute. So I changed the version to the one which has this attribute and it worked.